# asp.net strange cannot access file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I developed asp.net web app, I publish it to remote test server, it's all function is done. but when I publish it to product server, it throw "The process cannot access the file 'xxx.pdf' because it is being used by another process" exception. I do not know why?

Comment: Please let us know what version of IIS you are using. How is your App Pool setup and what Identity is it running under?

Comment: Can you share the code that writes the pdf file? More than likely you're not releasing the file handle soon enough.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `IUSR` has permissions to access the folder. Also `Anonymous User` might require permissions to access the folder as well.

Also check if the file is not in use..

Comment: "xxx.pdf" file can't be used by another process, because it is temp file, it is app created.

Comment: I had added IUSR and Anoymous Use permissions but it has same error.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned that particular temporary pdf file is created by your app. So it looks like `file is still being accessed by the process which created it`. And you are trying to access the same file from another process. Once the file is created at first place make sure its been released or any streams are disposed.

If you are simply trying to read the file from second process then make sure you set the required [FileShare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute when creating that file.